# AS3 to PHP, JSON type error? C/Ping the string works, $_posting the JSON itself doesn't

Tags: php, mysql, json, actionscript-3, flash

I'm passing a `JSON` object from flash `AS3` to `PHP`, which is then taken apart and passed to the DB.

```
In Flash:
    var jsonObject:Object = JSON.encode(currentlySelectedArray);

In PHP:
    $json_pieces_array = $_POST['jsonArray'];
    $json_obj = json_decode($json_pieces_array, true);
```

When I test my code by copy/pasting the output of **'trace (saveDataJSON.ToString());'** and putting it into my **'$_POST['jsonArray'] = '[[Valid JSONLint checked JSON here.]]'**, everything works fine and it gets pushed to the database.

But when I don't meddle and use the flash-sent `$_POST`, nothing pushes to the MYSQL DB.

**My question is twofold:**

1) What's the best way to bug test this sort of complication? I'm in the Flash interface.

2) What sorts of things should I be looking for? I already checked that the `JSON` being encoded was valid. Is there some sort of weird typecasting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

At first you have to debug request from flash. You can do it in several ways:

- create dummy file that does `var_dump($_REQUEST);`;
- add `file_put_contents('my_dump_file.txt', var_export($_REQUEST, true));` in existing script;
- check your webserver logs;
- debug you script with debugger (xdebug or similar).

Then you should check your PHP script. Try to `var_dump($_REQUEST);` on the top and exactly before `json_decode`. It can be so that `$_POST['jsonArray']` is overwritten somewhere else.

I guess that the problem is between flash and php. In most cases there is simply misspelling or `$_POST` is mixed with `$_GET`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the file_put_contents thing! That really, really helps for a new PHP coder, and let me figure out that GoDaddy had magic quotes enabled.